# How can I read the docstring of a python function guideline with help from cmd?

Tags: python

I would like to run the command help(guidelines) from cmd, to print the docstring of the function guidelines, placed in my main.py

```
def guidelines():
"""Docstring"""
```

I get the error: `guidelines : The term 'guidelines' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the nam e, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.`

What is the proper way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should first import the guidelines function from your file. Make sure you are in the directory where `main.py` exists

```
from main import guidelines

help(guidelines)
```

Answer (score 0):

Go to your script's(which has `guidelines` function in it) directory, open CMD (e.g. by typing cmd on the address bar), write "python" to enter to the REPL. then :

(my script is called `file1.py`)

```
>>> from file1 import guidelines
>>> help(guidelines)
Help on function guidelines in module file1:

guidelines()
    Docstring
```